# How does cost_complexity_pruning_path in sklearn calculate effective alphas when pruning a decision tree?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cart, pruning

I know when pruing `DecisionTreeRegressor`, we can leverage `cost_complexity_pruning_path` method to get a list of effective alphas. But how this method calculates the alphas?